# Crossfilter: can still access disposed-of dimension

Tags: crossfilter

I'm just testing certain aspects of crossfilter out. I've created a dimension called typeDim and then run typeDim.dispose(). The command is working because when I create 31 dimension prior to typeDim, the dispose command makes space for an extra one. However when I run console.log(typeDim.top(3)) *after* the disposal, three facts are still printed out. I would have expected an error.

```
    var typeDimension = facts.dimension(function(d){ return d.type; });
    typeDimension.dispose();
    console.log(typeDimension.top(3));
```

Outputs:

```
[Object,Object,Object]
```

Does anyone know why I can still access typeDim after disposing of it? Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this got down-voted. Perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you dispose of a Crossfilter dimension, all the references to the dimension within Crossfilter should be disposed of, which will allow the browser's garbage collection to delete the dimension object. The column for the dimension in Crossfilter's internal filter array will also be deleted. However, if you keep a reference to the dimension around, the dimension object will not get deleted.

Off the top of my head, a few things this means:

- `dimension.top` and `dimension.bottom` will still return values.
- `dimension.filter` should no longer have any affect on the Crossfilter for this dimension.
- If any filters were in place on the dimension, they will be removed from the Crossfilter

It's probably best, when you dispose of a dimension, to also try to remove any references to the dimension help in your own code so that the system can garbage-collect all the dimension objects. If you don't do this you will end up with what is essentially a memory leak, though it should no longer affect your Crossfilter until you actually run out of memory.